# React Render Multiple Route elements in single Routes element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I cant seem to render multiple Route elements in a single Routes element. I would like to have a multiple Route elements in a single Routes element since they are both updated dynamically. Does the old syntax/style not work?

Code example:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './Header';
import Home from './Home';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    // use BEM naming convention
    <Router>
      <div className="app">
        <Routes>
          {/* This one works */}
          {/* <Route path="/" element={<><Header /><Home /></>} /> */}

          {/* But this doesnt: */}
          <Route path="/" element={<Header />} />
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />

        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: There should be only one `Route` per path you want to match. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Well I need to do something like so, and it is not working: 
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<><Header /><Home /></>} />

          <Route path="/checkout" >
            <h1>I AM A CHECKOUT!</h1>
          </Route>
          
        </Routes>

Comment: I have a header (navbar) and a home (body of page) element I would like to add to the Route with the same path. Sorry If I am not making myself clear. Also, adding a new path does not work if it is in the same Routes element.

Answer (score 1):

There should be only one `Route` per path you want to match. In `react-router-dom@6` all routes are exclusively matched, the `Routes` component serves a similar purpose to, and is the spiritual successor of, the RRDv5 `Switch` component.

If you are trying to render common UI logic/components then the recommended way is to use what are called [Layout Routes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes) that renders the common logic/UI and an [`Outlet` component](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/outlet) for nested `Route` components to render their `element` into.

If you want to render a `Header` component on specific routes then create a layout component that renders the `Header` and `Outlet` and wrap the routes you want to render with `Header`.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from '../path/to/Header';

const HeaderLayout = () => (
  <>
    <Header />
    <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render content here
  </>
);

export default HeaderLayout;
```

...

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import HeaderLayout from './HeaderLayout';
import Home from './Home';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    // use BEM naming convention
    <Router>
      <div className="app">
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<HeaderLayout />}>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} /> // <-- nested route
            ... other routes with Header
          </Route>

          ... other routes w/o Header
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Great, this makes sense. Thanks for quick and clear answer Drew.

Comment: @Clouseau Welcome, glad to help. Cheers and good luck!